# ASMX Web Service receive large amount of data

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, asmx

I'm working on solution that uploads large amount of data through asmx web service to the server. I have implemented transfer code on a client like this:

```
service.ReceiveCompleted += MethodComplete;

public void Transfer(string data)
{
    service.ReceiveAsynk(data);
}

private void MethodComplete(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    service.DoWork(e.Result);
}
```

Transfer method argument string is compressed with deflate stream
Service use certificate and works via SSL/TLS,
but when I start upload data I receive randomly: "Unable to connect to remote server" or 
"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
Also the error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" occurs only then the compressed string is more than 200Kb." 
Any advices?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but is there some reason you're using ASMX services instead of WCF? ASMX is a legacy technology not meant to be used for new development.

Comment: We have old infrastructure and we havent any experience in WCF

Comment: "I am running Windows Server 2000" would be a very good reason to still write ASMX services. It would also be a very good reason to upgrade to a 21st Century OS.

Comment: Can you recommend me any good article or blog to quick start in WCF please ?

Comment: I recommend upgrading to .NET 4.0 at least (4.5/VS2012 releases Very Soon), then just creating a "WCF Service Project", then look at the code. Then, create a new console (or Winforms, or Webforms) application and use "Add Service Reference" to consume the new service. Note how easy that was. Then start making changes to turn that into a useful service. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info.

Comment: And if I want to use another web service on a client side which communicate with server side web service?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15285/discussion-between-windman-and-john-saunders)

Comment: WCF can do that easily. You can host a WCF service just about anywhere, including in a "client" application. ASMX services can only be hosted in IIS.

Comment: @JohnSaunders `ASMX services can only be hosted in IIS.` Not true. I have written many standalone apps that host `WebService`s

Comment: @JohnSaunders With the help of .Net Remoting

Comment: Huh? What does Remoting have to do with ASMX services?

Comment: @JohnSaunders `Huh?`. funny.  Remoting Server(using HttpChannel) + a class inhereting from WebService + SdlChannelSink to generate `wsdl`

Comment: @L.B: Seriously bad hack. That's not hosting an ASMX service. That's using remoting to make a Remoting service out of a class derived from `WebService`. You're not even running the ASMX web service infrastructure. On top of that all, Remoting is deprecated.

Comment: So why are you so curious about how I did it? `Seriously bad hack.` If you say so :)

Comment: @L.B: there's an old msdn mag article on hosting aspx/asmx without IIS. I've been using this technique for years for hosting web apps in windows services without iis. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with our old project which was using .asmx web services. However, the limit in our case was 100KB. We have found out that the following Web.config property controls the size of data which can be posted to .asmx:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1100000"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

`maxJsonLength` is in bytes and defaults to 100KB. Our project was using .Net v4.8.

Hope this helps someone.